# AWS: Is createLogGroup operation idempotent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using [Node SDK for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/), I have a question regarding the [createLogGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#createLogGroup-property) and [createLogStream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#createLogStream-property) operations, are these operations idempotent? i.e I can call create multiple times without having to worry about duplication or error.

Has anyone tried this before? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not idempotent.  Calling them again with the same names will cause an error.  For instance, if you follow the link through to [the underlying `CreateLogGroup` API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogGroup.html), you can see one of [the possible error responses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLogGroup.html#API_CreateLogGroup_Errors) is:

> **ResourceAlreadyExistsException**
>
> The specified resource already exists.
>
> HTTP Status Code: 400